# What Microsoft SQL join to use

Tags: sql

I don't have a clue as to how to proceed with this as I am new to SQL. I have a two giant tables each with about 70,000 rows with the data of following type:

Table 1:

```
A S D1
A S D2
A S D3
B S C
B S E1
B S E2
```

Table 2:

```
A S D1
B S E2
```

I want to get the following:

```
A S D1
B S C
B S E2
```

Edit:
I need to have all data which is intersection of Tables 1 and 2. I also need to discard from Table 1, data which matches across columns 1 and 2 but not on column 3.

Comment: Is there any condition to get the above data? With INNER JOIN, you can get A S D1 and B S E2. But what about B S C?

Comment: Added answer to your comment in edit.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query?noredirect=1#comment391934_333952

Comment: Could you re-edit your question, show column names and give better context to what you are trying to do.  Why would you get B/S/C when looking for B/S/E2.  Your sample data and declarations of tables is a poor sample.

Comment: You need to first look at better defining your requirements. I can see no reason why you would get B S C but not A S D2, A S D3 and B S E1 if all you care about if that the third one doesn't match. So you really need to do a better job of defining exactly what you want for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need two queries:

```
    SELECT TABLE1.A,TABLE1.B,TABLE1.C 
from TABLE1 inner join TABLE2 on TABLE1.A = TABLE2.A and TABLE1.B = TABLE2.B  and TABLE1.C = TABLE2.C
```

-- for the intersection

```
    SELECT TABLE1.A,TABLE1.B,TABLE1.C 
from TABLE1 inner join TABLE2 on TABLE1.A = TABLE2.A and TABLE1.B = TABLE2.B 
WHERE TABLE1.C <> TABLE2.C
```

-- for the discards

Comment: I think, your query will return only matched row not for B S C.